# SQL Server stored procedure with foreach

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a webshop and I want to use a stored procedure to lower the stocks of products when they are sold.

My current stored procedure does not work if there are duplicate products. So I thought of using a foreach in my stored procedure. But I am not familiar with this. Maybe you can help me?

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateStock]
    (@OrderID INT)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Products 
    SET Stock = Stock -1 
    FROM Products 
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductId = OrderDetails.ProductID 
    WHERE OrderDetails.OrderID = @OrderID
END
```

Comment: I didn't see any issue with this stored procedure not working with duplicate records.

Comment: There's no issue with this working with duplicate records, and a foreach in SQL is a seriously bad idea (it requires a CURSOR - Google *why are SQL cursors bad*). Please [edit] your post to include sample data for both `Products` and `OrderDetails` that demonstrate the issue using the procedure you've posted above.

Comment: Also, if this is a real site and not educational, you might want to handle reducing the stock only if the result would be >=0 to prevent orders for quantities not in stock. OR at least  handle when the order quantity is greater than the current stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is a bit off. What if an order detail had more than one item in it (usually an order detail would have a quantity field).

What you would normally do is something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateStock](@OrderID int)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Products 
SET Stock = Stock - (select sum(quantity) from orderdetails od where od.productid = products.productid and od.orderid = @orderid)
FROM Products 
Where productid in (select productid from orderdetails od where od.orderid = @orderid)

END
```

I don't guarantee the syntax but it should give you an idea of how it can be done. This would allow for a quantity > 1 on any one order detail and more than one order detail for the same product.